# How to let PowerBI read dot as decimal in csv

Tags: powerbi, decimal

I use R output csv file for powerbi
and the decimal in the file is dot

e.g. 27.25
and the PowerBI treat this as Text rather than number.
How should I fix this?

because this is .csv file, I will not able to change 27.25   to 27,25
I tried to change the 'reginal setting' to 'English''chinese''us'...not work.

any suggestion? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functionality `Using Locale` to transform a column to a desired region.

So, I have loaded these values as an example

[image]

With `Using Locale`, I can transform decimals on the expected locality, in this case, any country that uses dots as decimal, I will use `English (United States)`.

### Step 1

[image]

### Step 2

[image]

### Output

[image]